# Issue with written data format in fortran stream file

Tags: io, format, fortran

I'm trying to do a fortran subroutine to look for local maxima in a array of lenght n.

The program Grabs a 5 lenght array of the original n-lenght array and looks of the maxima is in the position 3. Then moves foreward with the to the next posible 5-lenght array in the n-lenght array.

I know this works, the problem is that i want to keep the maxima values, togheter with the correspondon wf and m parameters. So what im trying to do is write 3 files with this data, and loop them.

Here count_peak is a external variable, because i will loop this routine over several n-lenght arrays, and i want to keep counting the maxima peaks.

I know this is working, the problem i have is that when i read the files, the numbers and the lenght of the file seem to be wrong.

Here is the code:

```
subroutine local_max_bif_v2(valdata,size_data,compare_size,count_peak,debug)
    !************************************************
    ! makes an dim(compare_size) array from data. if the maximum value is in the  middle of the array (localdata(2)) saves the value to a binary file
    !************************************************
    use constants !Module that defines the changing parameters for the bifurcation

    integer, intent(in) :: debug
    integer, intent(in) :: size_data !input array lenght.
    real(8), dimension(size_data), intent(in) :: valdata !input array
    integer(4), intent(in) :: compare_size !even number, greater than 3 (3 or 5 give fast, good results on soft data.)
    integer(4), intent(inout) :: count_peak

    real(8), dimension(compare_size) :: localdata
    real(8) :: peak
    integer(4) :: peak_index
    integer(4), dimension(1) :: maxind
    integer(4) :: midpoint
    integer(4) :: j


    if (debug.eq.1) then
        print*,
        print*, '*************************************'
        print*, 'debug info for local_max_bif:  '
        print*,
        !print*, 'local_max_biff goes from : ', size_data-evaluate_lenght, 'to ', size_data-compare_size
    end if

    midpoint=(1+compare_size)/2
    OPEN(2,file='peak.in',form='unformatted',status='unknown',access='stream')
    OPEN(3,file='varw.in',form='unformatted',status='unknown',access='stream')
    OPEN(4,file='varm.in',form='unformatted',status='unknown',access='stream')

    do j=1,size_data-compare_size
        localdata=valdata(j:j+compare_size-1)
        maxind=maxloc(localdata)
        if (maxind(1).eq.(midpoint)) then
            peak=localdata(midpoint)
            count_peak=count_peak+1
            peak_index=j+midpoint-1
            WRITE(2) peak
            WRITE(3) wf
            WRITE(4) m
        end if
    end do
    CLOSE(2)
    CLOSE(3)
    CLOSE(4)

    if (debug.eq.1) then
        print*, 'last peak index: ', peak_index
        print*, 'amount of peaks', count_peak
        print*, '*************************************'
        print*,
    endif

    return


    !To do: -need  to add a way to test if the new peak is repeated or not. then if not, add no the file the new one

end subroutine
```

Comment: You never actually calculate `wf` and `m` before writing the values to file.

Comment: Also, you are probably off by one: shouldn't it read `do j=1,size_data-compare_size + 1`?

Comment: Stream access is Fortran 2003, there is no reason for tags fortran90 or fortran95.

Comment: Thanks!  . M  And wf come from the constants module.

Comment: Maybe i could put the +1 there. But it shouldn't change anything since it only counts and writes the peaks it finds.

Comment: The program actually works the first time it runs, I think the problem is when I loop it, maybe something to do with the end of file when I close it ?